# Punction is starting to be put at the start of my line

Tags: html, css, punctuation

So this may be a simple mistake, and I can't really post my whole code because it's extremely long. But long story short.

When I input

```
  <blockquote STYLE="text-align: center"> <div align="right">  <b>Well I'll Be <br><br><br> I'm Alive...</b></blockquote> </div>
```

This is the outcome

```
 Well I'll Be ...I'm Alive
```

I'm sure this is something simple that I'm screwing up.

Any suggestions? ALSO, the really weird thing is if I add a letter after the ellipsis the punctuation will be corrected..

Comment: What browser do you see this in? This isn't happening in Chrome. Also, you have a rogue `</blockquote>` in there.

Comment: Looks fine in IE7 also - about the only thing I can guess is to clear your browser cache (assuming at some point you had the elipsis before the "I'm alive" in prior testing).

Comment: where is your <blockquote> start tag? working fine for me to in chrome

Comment: Its on the line above it, forgot to add        <div align="Right" class="title">
      <blockquote STYLE="text-align: center">

Comment: hey its working  perfectly....... in which browser your checking?

Comment: Tried on other browsers, still the same for my site.

Comment: unschoolme.org - its a picture site for my school because everything is else is blocked so youll have to scroll down the the how racist are you picture...just didn't feel like put "IM DAMN RACIST" on here.

Comment: it is working fine for the url unschoolme.org. what exactly yoyr looking for?

Comment: About the tenth caption/picture down it doesn't put the ellipses at the start of the fourth line? It goes "I'm DAMN ...Racist" it's supposed to be "I'm DAMN Racist..."

Comment: Did your problem resolved by my answer if yes then please mark it as answer.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine in firefox too. I have checked that. kindly clear the history and check it again.

Edit

```
.wrdLatest{
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Remove this direction property from style sheet. Will resolve your issue for all punctuation.

Comment: what version of firefox your using?

Comment: The latest, I did try on chrome and internet explorer too.

Comment: Kindly check the answer given above.